# Ruby send JSON request

Tags: ruby, json, httprequest

How do I send a JSON request in ruby? I have a JSON object but I dont think I can just do `.send`. Do I have to have javascript send the form?

Or can I use the net/http class in ruby?

With header - content type = json and body the json object?

Answer (score 91):

```rb
uri = URI('https://myapp.com/api/v1/resource')
body = { param1: 'some value', param2: 'some other value' }
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
response = Net::HTTP.post(uri, body.to_json, headers)
```

Comment: I like your suggestion to use URI to handle the hostname and port, which otherwise is quite tedious. But you forgot to set uri.path in Post.new(...): `req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})`

Comment: Simplest, cleanest response.  This is great.

Comment: `http.request(req).read_body` to read the response body. Great!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's changed in 2.4.1 but my god. That syntax is gross. It knows it has the URI from the Post.new() so why do you have to repass the values, split up, in start(). Gross. No wonder there's so many other packages in ruby that deal with http.

Answer (score 55):

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

def create_agent
    uri = URI('http://api.nsa.gov:1337/agent')
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
    req.body = {name: 'John Doe', role: 'agent'}.to_json
    res = http.request(req)
    puts "response #{res.body}"
rescue => e
    puts "failed #{e}"
end
```

Comment: Which exception should be specified

Comment: For https requests just add: http.use_ssl = true.

Answer (score 17):

[HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) makes this a bit easier I think (and works with nested json etc, which didn't seem to work in other examples I've seen.

```
require 'httparty'
HTTParty.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users", body: {user: {email: 'user1@example.com', password: 'secret'}}).body
```

Answer (score 8):

This works on ruby 2.4 HTTPS Post with JSON object and the response body written out.

```
require 'net/http' #net/https does not have to be required anymore
require 'json'
require 'uri'

uri = URI('https://your.secure-url.com')
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
  request.body = {parameter: 'value'}.to_json
  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
  puts "response #{response.body}"
end
```

Answer (score 7):

real life example, notify [Airbrake API about new deployment](https://airbrake.io/docs/api/#create-deploy-v4) via NetHttps

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/https'
require 'json'

class MakeHttpsRequest
  def call(url, hash_json)
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.to_s)
    req.body = hash_json.to_json
    req['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    # ... set more request headers 

    response = https(uri).request(req)

    response.body
  end

  private

  def https(uri)
    Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).tap do |http|
      http.use_ssl = true
      http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    end
  end
end

project_id = 'yyyyyy'
project_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
url = "https://airbrake.io/api/v4/projects/#{project_id}/deploys?key=#{project_key}"
body_hash = {
  "environment":"production",
  "username":"tomas",
  "repository":"https://github.com/equivalent/scrapbook2",
  "revision":"live-20160905_0001",
  "version":"v2.0"
}

puts MakeHttpsRequest.new.call(url, body_hash)
```

Notes:

in case you doing authentication via Authorisation header set header `req['Authorization'] = "Token xxxxxxxxxxxx"`  or http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html

Comment: ...but honestly this is cool and all but in real live I would  just use HTTParty  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491995/473040 :)  ...especially if you are dealing with https handling

Comment: requiring uri is useless as it is already required by net/http

Comment: @equivalent8: "in real life I would just use HTTParty" - that is, unless you're building a lean gem, or otherwise don't want another dependency. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  agree ...unless you are building gem/lib (or Ruby based microservice) where you don't want to introduce unnecessary dependencies ;)

Answer (score 3):

A simple json POST request example for those that need it even simpler than what Tom is linking to:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI.parse("http://www.example.com/search.json")
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"search" => "Berlin"})
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but post_form translates the parameters into the ?key=value&key=value syntax. If you want to do a POST with the request body set to a JSON string, I think you need a different solution.

Comment: This doesn't work with deeply nested json. Anything beyond the first level becomes a string.

Comment: Doens't just look like. It WORKS. It's simple sure. but for simple things like the example I have given it works just fine

Comment: This is fundamentally not a JSON request. This is a urlencoded body. There is no JSON. The header even says as much. This does not work with any example, ever.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  It's a POST in mime/multipart, to a url that says "json" in it.

Comment: You can make this a JSON request like so: `require "json"; uri = …; Net::HTTP.post(uri, { "search" => "Berlin" }.to_json, "Content-Type" => "application/json")`

Answer (score 3):

It's 2020 - nobody should be using `Net::HTTP` any more and all answers seem to be saying so, [use a more high level gem such as Faraday](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2011/07/faraday-advanced-http/) - [Github](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday)

---

That said, what I like to do is a wrapper around the HTTP api call,something that's called like

`rv = Transporter::FaradayHttp[url, options]`

because this allows me to fake HTTP calls without additional dependencies, ie:

```
  if InfoSig.env?(:test) && !(url.to_s =~ /localhost/)
    response_body = FakerForTests[url: url, options: options]

  else
    conn = Faraday::Connection.new url, connection_options
```

Where the faker looks something like [this](https://gist.github.com/bbozo/fac8a5100d2126a3b7837d1d9231d89b)

I know there are HTTP mocking/stubbing frameworks, but at least when I researched last time they didn't allow me to validate requests efficiently and they were just for HTTP, not for example for raw TCP exchanges, this system allows me to have a unified framework for all API communication.

---

Assuming you just want to quick&dirty convert a hash to json, send the json to a remote host to test an API and parse response to ruby this is probably fastest way without involving additional gems:

```
JSON.load `curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'Accept:application/json' -X POST localhost:3000/simple_api -d '#{message.to_json}'`
```

Hopefully this goes without saying, but don't use this in production.

Comment: You can't do this using NTLM authentication. So Net::HTTP is still the only one that has a library that supports it.

Comment: Disagree with the 'nobody should be using `Net::HTTP`' assertion

Comment: Downvoted because of the `nobody should be using Net::HTTP any more` @bbozo

Answer (score 3):

I like this light weight http request client called `unirest'

`gem install unirest`

usage:

```
response = Unirest.post "http://httpbin.org/post", 
                        headers:{ "Accept" => "application/json" }, 
                        parameters:{ :age => 23, :foo => "bar" }

response.code # Status code
response.headers # Response headers
response.body # Parsed body
response.raw_body # Unparsed body
```

Answer (score 2):

The net/http api can be tough to use.

```
require "net/http"

uri = URI.parse(uri)

Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port).start do |client|
  request                 = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
  request.body            = "{}"
  request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  client.request(request)
end
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. You need to initialize Net::HTTP with #start like so: `Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => true) do |client|`

Comment: Works with ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {a: {b: [1, 2]}}.to_json
uri = URI 'https://myapp.com/api/v1/resource'
https = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
https.use_ssl = true
https.post2 uri.path, data, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using my favourite http request library in ruby:

```
resp = HTTP.timeout(connect: 15, read: 30).accept(:json).get('https://units.d8u.us/money/1/USD/GBP/', json: {iAmOne: 'Hash'}).parse
resp.class    
  => Hash
```