# Additional quotes in parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest

i'm trying to learn simple stuff a make HTTP request to rails app.
 the problem is, when i try to make HTTP post request to my rails app, code is :

```
uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:4000/posts")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data( :post=> {"name" => "My query", "title" => "50"} )
response = http.request(request)
```

when i look into console for incoming post request, the output is:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-02 16:14:12 +0100
Processing by PostsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"post"=>"{\"name\"=>\"My query\", \"title\"=>\"50\"}"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "{\"name\"=>\"My query\", \"title\"=>\"50\"}":String):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:72:in `post_params'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

Look closely on parameters. Why does ist add additional quotation marks? how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are sending a stringified JSON object. I don't know what set_form_data is doing but you should be converting your request .to_json.
Look at this so question for reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024805/ruby-send-json-request).