# Posting Ruby data in JSON format with Net/http

Tags: ruby, json, net-http

I have this ruby file:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'uri'
    #test data

newAcctJson ='{
  "type": "Credit Card",
  "nickname": "MoreTesting",
  "rewards": 2,
  "balance": 50
}'

    #creates a new account
def createAcct(custID, json)
    url = "http://api.reimaginebanking.com:80/customers/#{custID}/accounts?key=#{APIkey}"
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    myHash = JSON.parse(json)
    resp = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, myHash)
    puts(resp.body)
end
```

which attempts to create a new account. However I get `code: 400, invalid fields in account`. I tested the data independently, so I'm (relatively) certain that the json itself isn't in an incorrect format; the problem is in trying to submit the data in the hash format that the `post_Form` requires. Does anyone know a way to use ruby to directly post json data without converting to a hash first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby send JSON request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024805/ruby-send-json-request)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make a request object like so:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, 
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
request.body = newAcctJson
resp = http.request(request)
```

Comment: where is the `http` variable coming from?

Comment: @mr.musicman - the question shows `http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)`

Answer (score 4):

To combine the code from the question and @DVG's excellent answer:

```
require 'net/http'
#require 'json' - not needed for the example
require 'uri'

#test data
newAcctJson ='{
  "type": "Credit Card",
  "nickname": "MoreTesting",
  "rewards": 2,
  "balance": 50
}'

#creates a new account
def createAcct(custID, json)
  url = "http://api.reimaginebanking.com:80/customers/#{custID}/accounts?key=#{APIkey}"
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(
    uri.request_uri, 
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  )
  request.body = newAcctJson

  response = http.request(request)
  puts(response.body)
end
```