# json HTTP-POST request in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

How can I transform this `curl` command to a Ruby HTTP Request?

```
curl -k -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @/home/venafi/venafi-auth.json https://10.150.85.11/authorize/`
```

I don't know Ruby very well and I tried

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'

uri = URI.parse("https://10.150.85.1/authorize/")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
request.set_form_data({'Username' => 'user', 'Password' => 'Passw0rd'})
#request['foo'] = 'bar'
puts request
response =  http.request(request)
puts "Response\n #{response.code} \n#{response.message}: \n#{response.body.to_json}"
puts response
puts request

httpg = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
httpg.use_ssl = true
httpg.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
reqg = Net::HTTP::Get.new("uri.request_uri")

puts "Response\n #{reqg.body.to_json}"
```

But the only thing that I get is

> Net::HTTP::Post:0x00000001baab98
>   Response
>    202
>   Accepted:
>   ""
>   Net::HTTPAccepted:0x00000001bcac68
>        Net::HTTP::Post:0x00000001baab98
>        Response
>        null

While when I use `curl` I get an apikey.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO.  This is the start of a a good question, but in order for someone to answer it we need more information.  Can you please edit the question to explain in what way the code doesn't work?  SO focuses on fixing specific problems, so we need a specific problem to solve.

Comment: @WayneConrad I edited my question :)

Comment: Good that you've improved your question :). Please mind that I removed the sentence "Thank you" from your question. Since this is a Q&A based site, it is prefered to write clean questions, without sentences like "Thank you", "Hello fellow users" etc. Just a note ;). Welcome to SO.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024805/ruby-send-json-request