# Ignoring => when converting hash in ruby? How to properly convert hash?

Tags: json, ruby, http

I'm sending a post request, and this is the payload:

```
data = {updates: [{action: "create", user_id: "2", type: "view"}]}
```

but when I send it, the API says it was expecting:

```
{ action: \"create\", user_id: \"id\", type: \"type\" }
```

but it getting:

```
{:action=\u003e\\\"create\\\", :user_id=\u003e2\\\"2\\\", :type=\u003e\\\"view\\\"}\
```

The => is getting converted. I tried using `to_json` but that didn't help me.

How do I convert this properly? I think it has something to do with the nested array/hash because all the others work fine.

Also, I'm setting my request body and sending like so:

```
request.set_form_data(body)
https.request(request)
```

---

Looks like I need to use this syntax in order to pass set_form_data a nested hash:

`{'a[b]': 'c'}` is the same as `{'a' => {'b' => 'c'}}`

but is there a way to include the array? I need to have:

```
data = {updates: [{action: "create", user_id: "2", type: "view"}]}
```

in this notation.

Comment: Where's the code where you tried `to_json`? That should work.

Comment: Made some edits.

Comment: Assuming this is `Net::HTTP`, have you tried setting `request.body = send_data.to_json` (check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024805/ruby-send-json-request))

Comment: That's better but the relationship between `send_data` and your `set_form_data` code is not clear. Is this within the context of a unit test or within stand-alone code?

Comment: One thing that can make interfacing with a JSON API is a gem like [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) where like Rack is has plug-in encoder/decoders.

Comment: The error above was because I was sending a string to send_form_data, which takes a hash. I'm going to try using request.body and see that helps. Could send_form_data have trouble with nests hashes/arrays?

Comment: If you're using Net::HTTP then you want to assign your JSON to the `body` directly, bypassing `set_form_data`.

Comment: I figured out that you can't directly pass a nested hash to set_form_data and have to use the other notation (see my edits). Do you know of a way to include the array? I tried using body directly but was having issues.

Comment: I second the motion to use a gem built for API communication such as Faraday or HTTParty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, `set_form_data` does not accept arrays. It looks like a workaround if you wanted to continue using the `Net::HTTP` library is to encode the data and pass it to `request.body`.

`request.body = "updates[][action]=create&updates[][type]=view&updates[][user_id]=2"
request.content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

You could also create a custom function like they did in this post: http://cloudlines.tumblr.com/post/653645115/postput-arrays-with-ruby-nethttp-setformdata

Check out this post on changing complex objects into a querystring: https://coderwall.com/p/uh8kiw/pass-arrays-objects-via-querystring-the-rack-rails-way.

Hope that helps!